# How to use rpy2 to perform Wilcox test on two lists without sometimes getting the error: "not enough (finite) 'x' observations"

Tags: r, python

I have some python/rpy2 code that supports AB testing that usually successfully runs a Wilcox test on two lists of floating values (donations in dollars). But sometimes it throws the following error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/rpy2/robjects/__init__.py", line 423, in __call__
res = super(RFunction, self).__call__(*new_args, **new_kwargs)
rinterface.RRuntimeError: Error in wilcox.test.default(numeric(0), numeric(0)) : 
not enough (finite) 'x' observations
```

Here's the code. rs is a result from a mysql query. The amount values are all non-null ranging from 1 to 1000 -- but almost all from 5 to 50.

```
a1 = []
a2 = []
r = robjects.r
for row in rs: 
    if row['banner'] == bans[1]:
        a1.append(row['amount'] )
    else:
        a2.append( row['amount'] )
v1 = robjects.FloatVector(a1)
v2 = robjects.FloatVector(a2)
wilcox_result =  r['wilcox.test'](v1, v2) 
print  "Wilcox test of means p= %.6f" % wilcox_result[2][0] # the p-value
```

It works on about 60% of my ab tests. But gives this error in the rest. I haven't noticed any pattern in the data that might be causing the error. And I can't find any documentation on this error for rpy2.

Comment: A pity `rs` is not provided to help reproduce the problem...

Comment: to reproduce the error I'd need to give two lists of several thousand values. Is there a way to do that here?

Comment: A subset of the values showing the problem would do.

Answer (score 1):

The `RRuntimeError` exception is reporting an error message coming from R.
Here it is:

> Error in wilcox.test.default(numeric(0), numeric(0)) : 
>   not enough (finite) 'x' observations

This means that in 40% of your tests (since you are reporting 60% success) a1 or a2 (may be even both) do not have any numerical value (either vectors of length 0, which you can test with `if len(a1)==0 or len(a2)==0` to trace the problem, or all values are NAs, Infinite, or NaN)